# Unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting the following error and I just cant find the solution to the problem. Might be anyone be able to help me?

```
 DB::table('videos')->insert(
             ['video_id'        => $videos[$i]->title],
             ['url']            => $videos[$i]->url],
             ['default_thumb']  => $videos[$i]->default_thumb],
             ['thumb']          => $videos[$i]->thumb],
             ['publish_date']   => $videos[$i]->publish_date],
             ['tags']           => $videos[$i]->tags]
           );
```

The error message is:

```
FatalErrorException in VideoController.php line 33:
syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct syntax for `insert()` method:

```
DB::table('videos')->insert([
         'video_id'       => $videos[$i]->title,
         'url'            => $videos[$i]->url,
         'default_thumb'  => $videos[$i]->default_thumb,
         'thumb'          => $videos[$i]->thumb,
         'publish_date'   => $videos[$i]->publish_date,
         'tags'           => $videos[$i]->tags
    ]);
```

Comment: Should have closed as typo...

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will solve your problem

```
DB::table('videos')->insert(
             ['video_id'        => $videos[$i]->title,
             'url'            => $videos[$i]->url,
             'default_thumb'  => $videos[$i]->default_thumb,
             'thumb'          => $videos[$i]->thumb,
             'publish_date'   => $videos[$i]->publish_date,
             'tags'           => $videos[$i]->tags]
           );
```